# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header on Angular 2 but cURL works fine

Tags: angular

I am developing an application using Angular 2 and I find the following error when I try to make an API call:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:9090/conf. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:5555' is therefore not allowed access.

Here, there are two examples of my calls:

```
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';

// ...

@Injectable()
export class ConfService {

  // ...

  getConf(): Observable<string[]> {
    return this.http.get(
                      'http:localhost:9090/conf?id=1',
                      {
                        headers: {
                          'Accept': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8'
                        }
                      }
                    )
                    .map((res: Response) => res.json())
                    .catch(this.handleError);
  }

  setConf(conf: any[]): Observable<string[]> {
    return this.http.get(
                      'http:localhost:9090/conf?id=1',
                      conf,
                      {
                        headers: {
                          'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8'
                        }
                      }
                    )
                    .map((res: Response) => res.json())
                    .catch(this.handleError);
  }

}
```

**However, when I use cURL it works!**

```
$ curl -XPUT 'localhost:9090/configuration?id=1' \
> -H 'Content-Type: application/json'
> -d '{"conf":1234}'
Success!
$ curl -XGET 'localhost:9090/conf?id=1'
{"conf":1234}
```

What is happening here?

Thanks

Comment: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cors-toggle/omcncfnpmcabckcddookmnajignpffnh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because of browser security, a general CORS issue in browser. Your web app is running at localhost:5050 and server at localhost:9090. Browser won't allow to access another host with different port number. The solution is handle the CORS in your server (i.e in your app running at localhost:9090)

Comment: My Spring app uses Tomcat and I cannot boot it if there is another app (my Angular client) using the same port.

Comment: Of course, they have to run in different port. Configure your spring app to have CORS headers.